# manage.py no such file or dir

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I've got this Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6.9-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /usr/src/app

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "run -h 0.0.0.0"]  #  <--
```

On the last line I'm getting `python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  users:
    build:
      context: ./users
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - './services/users:/usr/src/app'
    ports:
      - 5001:5000
    environment:
      - FLASK_APP=project/__init__.py
      - FLASK_ENV=development
```

I've got `manage.py` in the same directory as the Dockerfile (located in `users` dir). Where does it look for it ?

Comment: How are you running the container?  (Are you hiding the image’s contents with a `docker run -v` option?)

Comment: @DavidMaze No, I'm executing docker-compose.yml from outside of the directory. I'll add it to the post so others can see.

Comment: So, yes, you’re hiding the image contents with `volumes:`.  Try removing that declaration.

Comment: @DavidMaze  I didn't remove but what helped was editing it to `'./users:/usr/src/app`. Now it runs. Put it as an answer and I'm gonna tick it off for you.

Answer (score 1):

Issue solved by editing `volumes:
      - './services/users:/usr/src/app'`

to:

```
volumes:
  - './users:/usr/src/app'
```